# Getting error using "rails server" command for the first time following Lynda tutorial on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

OS: Windows 7 64 bit
Rails version:4.2.0
Using MySQL

So, I've completely installed Ruby on Rails, MySQL, MySQL gems as showed in the lynda tutorials...i'm new to ruby on rails.
When i created my first Application, and used the command "rails server" to start WebRICK...it gave me the following error as follows:

**

```
693 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/form_options_helper.rb
  694 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_supp
ort/number_helper.rb
  695 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/number_helper.rb
  696 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_supp
ort/core_ext/module/concerning.rb
  697 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_supp
ort/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb
  698 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_supp
ort/core_ext/module.rb
  699 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/re
cord_identifier.rb
  700 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/record_tag_helper.rb
  701 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/rendering_helper.rb
  702 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_supp
ort/core_ext/string/access.rb
  703 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers/translation_helper.rb
  704 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/he
lpers.rb
  705 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets
/rails/helper.rb
  706 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets
/rails/version.rb
  707 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine/con
figuration.rb
  708 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/source_ann
otation_extractor.rb
  709 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/applicatio
n/configuration.rb
  710 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets
/railtie.rb
  711 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/all.rb
  712 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2/version.rb
  713 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2/error.rb
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
C:\Users\Neha\My Documents\www\simple_cms>
```

**

---

This is just a section of a larger number of lines...
Now, i'm not able to figure out what the problem here is!

Can anybody please let me know how this issue can be resolved?

Comment: source link that you referred to download? I would suggest to one of linux distros with RoR development.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you might need to remove the installation completely and install again. It happened to me before on Windows 8.